# Text adjustment

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

When I am writing (document class article), Latex automatically adjust the length of the paragraph to fit at least two lines on the next page (my paragraph can't fit entirely on one page). Is there a way where I could change the default setting to three lines on the next page?

Comment: note that tex does not adjust the linebreaking to change the length of the paragraph. If you force three lines over, then the paragraph is not extended: the current page will just be broken earlier and rely on white space on the page to expand.

Answer (score 5):

You can control the number of widow lines with the `nowidow` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2-7]

~

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```